# Javascript / HTML Question: Taking an input value from a form, and using this to send user to a URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url

Thanks for reading.  I'm a novice with Javscript, and have done a lot of searches to try and figure this out... (to no avail)

I'm trying to create a situation where the user inputs a single word on a form.  And then when they click a submit button, the website takes the word from the input, appends it on the end of an incomplete URL, and sends them to that completed URL.

It's easy probably easy to see why this doesn't work to some of you.  And also, embarassingly, I imagine a completely different approach would be best.

Your advice is appreciated.

```
<form action="https://vrnaut.neocities.org/"  method="get">
  <label for="MyForm">Enter One Word:</label>
  <input type="text" id= "OneWord" name="OneWord" required>
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<script>
function myFunction(form) {
  var GoHere = form.OneWord.value;
  location.replace("https://vrnaut.neocities.org/" + GoHere);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You never pass anything to `myFunction`... but the only argument passed to an EventListener is the EventObject, so you would want to wrap that function in another and pass in the argument that represents your form. You could just do like `function myFunction(){ location = 'https://vrnaut.neocities.org'+document.getElementById('OneWord').value.trim(); }`. Of course, if you don't want to parse the DOM every time the button is clicked then get the Node beforehand, assigning it to a variable for reuse.

Comment: For the same reason the inline `style` attribute is bad markup, inline `on*` JS handlers attributes are bad as well. CSS and JS should be in one place only, and that's their respective files or tags. Use `Element.addEventListener()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Place the button **inside** you form
- Never listen for buttons *click* - rather use the FORM's `"submit"` Event:

```js
const EL_form = document.querySelector("#myForm");
const EL_word = document.querySelector("#OneWord");

EL_form.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  location.replace(EL_form.action + EL_word.value);
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="https://vrnaut.neocities.org/" method="get">
  <label for="MyForm">Enter One Word:</label>
  <input type="text" id="OneWord" name="OneWord" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly.  I will try to learn from this example.

Unfortunately, I am brand new to this stackoverflow, so my upvotes (which I have given you) are recorded, but they won't show up until I have a reputation of 15.

Comment: @T.ShawnJohnson you'll soon be at 15. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is perfectly fine. All that's needed is a little tweaking.

```html
<form action="https://vrnaut.neocities.org/"  method="get">
  <label for="MyForm">Enter One Word:</label>
  <input type="text" id= "OneWord" name="OneWord" required>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this.parentElement)">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function myFunction(form) {
  var GoHere = form.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  location.replace("https://vrnaut.neocities.org/" + GoHere.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning that up for me!  Unfortunately, when put the word "believe" in there, this is where I am sent:

https://vrnaut.neocities.org/?OneWord=believe